# Human readable Coq output from command line

Tags: command-line, coq

I'm invoking Coq from command line on this simple input file:

```
$ cat AddingZero.v
Theorem plus_O_n : (forall n, O + n = n).
Proof.
  intros n.
  simpl.
  exact (eq_refl n).
Qed.
```

Here's how I do it:

```
$ coqc ./AddingZero.v ; echo $?
0
```

When I see the `0` output I know things went OK,
so I try to examine the output of Coq by doing:

```
$ vim ./AddingZero.vo
```

But I get some binary gibberish with that.
What am I doing wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.vo` are compiled `.v` file. They are not for human consumption.

The typical way to interact with a Coq file is to open it in a text editor with support for Coq (e.g. coqide, emacs with proofgeneral) and to step through the proof.

Alternatively, you can use a tool like [proviola](https://github.com/JasonGross/proviola-source) to generate an html+js file which will show the statements, the proofs and all the intermediate states the prover is in after each proof step.

Comment: When I open coqide and compile, it says `AddingZero.c successfully compiled` ... but how can I see the proof?

Comment: You can use the down arrow (or whatever the keyboard shortcut is) to step through the proof.

Comment: Oh I see it now ... thanks! can you maybe add the command line option for using proviola?